# How to make a jump difussion graphic

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, finance, mathematica-8

I have  to plot the next jump diffusion model using Mathematica or a similar tool:

[image: Equation of Jump Diffusion Model]

namely, a Geometric Brownian motion with compound Poisson jumps.

I can use any program for it.

Note:

I have found the next similar [code](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-random-processes/model-option-prices-using-merton-jump-diffusion.html)  but it does not work when I execute it using Mathematica 9.0, it errors out with

> ""The specification TransformedProcess[0.955\ t+j[t]+0.7\ w[t],{w\
>   [Distributed]WienerProcess[1,0.7],j[Distributed]\
>   CompoundPoissonProcess[1.3,NormalDistribution[0.92,0.425]]},t] is not
>   \ a random process recognized by the system. ""

Any help will be very useful :)

Comment: the code in the link says specifically "new in 10". Time to upgrade or start coding your own.

Comment: Just a note: StackOverflow doesn't load MathJax due to performance issues.  I turned your LaTeX equation into an image using [this tool](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php).  You may find it useful in the future.

Comment: Oh, yes. I didn´t realise it was only for 10. I have the 9, I wpuld have to try another option